# Algorithms for minimizing Moore automata

Tags: reference-request, automata, optimization, finite-automata, transducers

Brzozowski's algorithm can be extended to Moore automata but its time complexity is exponential in general. Is there any other algorithm for minimization of Moore automata? What are the running times of these algorithms if any?

Comment: Which Brzozowski's algorithm are you referring to? The one using  derivatives of regular expressions?

Comment: Welcome to SE Computer Science. Since you apparently did not yet read
the presentation of the site, you should know that it is a cooperative
work, based on technical exchange between users asking questions and
users who provide answers or comments. Thus it is consider proper to
answer users asking for more details in comments, to upvote good
answers or good comments (or other interesting questions or answers
that you read), and ultimately to accept the answer you consider best
for your questions by clicking the "check sign" (like a V) of the left
of the chosen answer.

Comment: Was the answer any use to you?

Answer (score 6):

**The original DFA minimization algorithm was actually designed for Moore Machines**, guided by their apparently more observable behavior.
But the algorithm presented here is a reconstruction from the DFA minimization,
since I discovered the historical evidence after the fact.

After Wikipedia (with some notational changes):

> A [Moore machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine) can be defined as a 6-tuple $(Q, q_0, \Sigma, \Pi, \delta, \gamma)$ consisting of the following:
>
> - a finite set of states $Q$
> - a start state (also called initial state) $q_0$ which is an element of $Q$
> - a finite set called the input alphabet $\Sigma$
> - a finite set called the output alphabet $\Lambda$
> - a transition function $\delta : Q \times \Sigma \rightarrow Q$ mapping a state and the input alphabet to the next state
> - an output function $\gamma : Q \rightarrow \Pi$ mapping each state to the output alphabet

From this definition, a Moore machine is a deterministic finite state
transducer.

I have no reference for minimization of Moore automata. However it
seems not too hard to imagine an algorithm, derived from the algorithm used for
deterministic finite state automata.

The idea in DFA minimization is based on the [Myhill-Nerode
characterization of regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem).

> Given a language $L$, and a pair of strings $x$ and $y$, define a
>     distinguishing extension to be a string $z$ such that exactly one of
>     the two strings $xz$ and $yz$ belongs to $L$. Define a relation
>     $R_L$ on strings by the rule that $x R_L y$ iff there is no
>     distinguishing extension for $x$ and $y$. It is easy to show that
>     $R_L$ is an equivalence relation on strings, and thus it divides the
>     set of all strings into equivalence classes.
>
> The Myhill-Nerode theorem states that $L$ is regular if and only if
>     $R_L$ has a finite number of equivalence classes, and moreover that
>     the number of states in the smallest deterministic finite automaton
>     (DFA) recognizing $L$ is equal to the number of equivalence classes
>     in $R_L$.

Indeed each state $q$ of the smallest DFA is such that $W_q$ as
defined above is one of the equivalence classes for the relation $R_L$.

For a non-minimal DFA for the regular language $L$, 
it is easy to show that each set $W_q$ contains
strings that all belong to a same equivalent class with respect to
$R_L$.

Hence, the minimization of the DFA actually consists of merging states
(considered as sets of equivalent strings), whenever it is shown that
two distinct states contain equivalent strings.

Two reasonably fast algorithms exists for that purpose, Moore
algorithm (1956) which is in time $O(n^2)$ and Hopcroft's algorithm
(1971) in time $O(n\log n)$.

The extension to Moore automata is best understood in redefining the
equivalence relation as $R_T$ for a transducer $T$. The relation $R_L$
was concerned with whether future input would lead equivalently to an
accepting state. The $R_T$ equivalence relation of Moore automata is
concerned with whether future input will produce the same output.

Hence, given a transducer $T$, and two strings $x$ and $y$, we define a
distinguishing extension to be a string $z$ such that $T(xz)=T(x)u$
and $T(yz)=T(y)v$ with $u\neq v$, i.e. such that the output behaviour
of the transducer differs for $z$ depending on whther it is following
$x$ or $y$.

Again, $R_T$ is an equivalence relation, dividing all strings in
$\Sigma^*$ into equivalence classes. In the case of a Moore machine,
these classes will again correspond to state of the minimal
transducer.

**The following algorithm mimics the Moore algorithm for DFA minimisation.**

We define an initial partition $\mathcal P$ of $Q$  into classes of states $S_e$ as follow:

$\forall e\in\Pi:\; S_e=\{q\in Q\mid \gamma(q)=e\}$

Then we split the classes in $\mathcal P$ as follows:

**repeat** successively for each class of states $S$, until none
  changes
$\ \ $ **repeat** $\forall a\in\Sigma,\;$
$\ \ \ \ $ **If** $ \exists S'\in \mathcal P,\; \forall q\in S,\; 
\delta(q,a)\in S'$  **then** do nothing
$\ \ \ \ $ **else** split $S$ into subsets $S_i$ such that
$\ \ \ \ \ \ $ for each
  subset $S_i$,  there is a different class $S'\in \mathcal P$ such that $ \forall q\in S_i,\; 
\delta(q,a)\in S'$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ $ (the subsets $S_i$ replace $S$ in $\mathcal P$)

When there is no class left that needs to be split, the remaining
classes of states will form the states of the minimal Moore
machine.

By construction, all states in a class have the same output which is
the output for the class.

Similarly, for any input $a\in\Sigma$, all states in a class go to some
state in the same other class, which defines the transition function
for the minimal Moore machine.

**Complexity analysis:** 
Let $n=|Q|$ be the number of states, and $s=|\Sigma|$ the size of the input alphabet.
The main loop is executed at most $n$ times, since each iteration must
split at least one class of states, and each class contains at least
one state. Each iteration of the loop examines each state a finite
number of times, and in proportion to the number of input symbols. Hence the complexity of the algorithm is $O(sn^2)$,
the same as that of the DFA minimization algorithm that served as a guideline
for this one.

I do not have any reference for this minimization of Moore
machines. Possibly it is included in his paper:

> Moore, Edward F (1956). "Gedanken-experiments on Sequential Machines". *Automata Studies*, Annals of Mathematical Studies (Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press) (34): 129-153.

This paper is the main reference introducing [Moore Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_machine). It is also the reference for [Moore's DFA minimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Moore.27s_algorithm). It should thus be surprising if the adaptation of the algorithm to the
minimization of Moore Machines were not at least suggested in that
paper. I did check the paper, and the version of the minimization
algorithm that is presented is actually for Moore machines, not for
DFA. The paper is well written, but the style of the time makes it a
bit harder to read. It is interesting to see that many of the ideas of the Myhill-Nerode theory of Finite State Machines are already sketched in this paper.

The more recent $O(sn\log n)$ [algorithm due to John Hopcroft (1971)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization#Hopcroft.27s_algorithm) should be similarly adaptable to Moore machines. It is not clear that there was any reason to publish this adaptation anywhere, and the [Hopcroft paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cdm/pdf/Hopcroft71.pdf) seems to have no reference to Moore machines.

Comment: @Raphael  A reference ... Well, you are lucky, I redesigned the algorithm, because I do not have access to a library. But since you asked for a reference, I got you one. You should like it. But I am not sure I would use it for teaching.

Comment: @Raphael The paper is interesting in its presentation that attempts to be very
intuitive, more operational than algebraic. I do not remember all
details of the contribution of Myhill and Nerode (two years later in
1958), and I did not read the paper carefully enough (I rather skimmed
it) but I am wondering if the theory should not be attributed to Moore
as well.

Answer (score 2):

A version of Brzozowski's algorithm using derivatives of regular expressions
is given in [2], Chapter 12, Section 4, where it is credited to
[4]. See [1] and [3] for the more general case of subsequential transducers (the terminology is a bit outdated and the term *sequential transducer* is probably more appropriate nowadays).

[1] C. Choffrut, Minimizing subsequential transducers: a survey, *Theoret. Comp. Sci.* **292** (2003), 131–143.

[2] S. Eilenberg, Automata, Languages and Machines, vol. A, Academic Press, 1974.

[3] J.-E. Pin, [A tutorial on sequential functions](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/Exposes/Sequential.pdf). (Slides)

[4] G. N. Raney, Sequential functions, *JACM* **5** (1958), 177–180.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the edit. Just perfect.

Answer (score 1):

[Brzozowski's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dfa_minimization#Brzozowski.27s_algorithm) is a bad starting point (if you are concerned with asymptotic worst-case runtime). Even Wikipedia tells you as much:

> As Brzozowski (1963) observed, reversing the edges of a DFA produces a non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA) for the reversal of the original language, and converting this NFA to a DFA using the standard powerset construction (constructing only the reachable states of the converted DFA) leads to a minimal DFA for the same reversed language. Repeating this reversal operation a second time produces a minimal DFA for the original language. The worst-case complexity of Brzozowski's algorithm is exponential, as there are regular languages for which the minimal DFA of the reversal is exponentially larger than the minimal DFA of the language,[6] but it frequently performs better than this worst case would suggest.

The algorithm has exponential worst-case runtime *even on DFA* because it computes an automaton for the reverse, which may have to be exponentially large. So your problem does not come from the extension to transducers.

Try to adapt another DFA-minimisation algorithm.